# Can AC/DC converter be fed with input voltage below its specified voltage range when it is supposed to be off?

Tags: power-supply, ac-dc

In a bathroom there is a 4 x 2.5 mm power cable. One hot conductor is for powering the main light, and the second one for powering the AC/DC converter for the LED strips.

However, when the main light is on, there is `50 VAC` on the second conductor. I have an AC/DC voltage converter with `90-250VAC/47-63Hz/0.23A/26W` input parameters, and `12VDC/1.67A/20W` output parameters.

I am wondering how safe it is to supply the AC/DC converter with that `50 VAC` when it is supposed to be off. Can it lead to an early break of the converter? Replacing the cable requires serious construction intervention that I would like to avoid.

Comment: Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you have and how it’s connected. Between what and what do you measure 50 V AC?

Answer (score 0):

As with any closely placed conductors, there is inter-wire capacitance and, that will couple a decent fraction of the live voltage to unconnected wires. So if you measure it with a high impedance voltmeter you are bound to see anything up to about 50% of the live voltage.

Without too much uncertainty you should connect your converter and LED strip and re-measure the voltage. The LED strip might flicker a bit or even remain on (maybe dimly) even though the switch should be deactivating it but, it's unlikely that the LED strip or converter will suffer any damage.

There's a good chance it will work fine and, that the re-measured voltage won't be more than maybe 10 volts when the wire is inactive.

Comment: I have measured the voltage after connecting the converter. Now, when the main light is on, the voltage on the converter input is 0 V. It is surprising that the whole 50 V has disappeared.

Comment: @AlBundy Did you read my answer? Did you understand why the voltage you originally measured was meaningless?

Comment: I did. What I do not understand is why the situation is different when the converter is connected, even when its switch is turned off. It is not like the inter-wire capacitance is gone in this case.

Comment: It will be presenting a load that is "stronger" than the capacitive reactance and thus reduces the voltage @AlBundy

Comment: What is the load of open circuit? The resistance of the air is relatively high.

Comment: There will be internal circuits that are taking a few mA even though you believe the device is off. Typical of these are line capacitors for reducing emissions. These are often the very first thing inside a power supply i.e. they are always connected @AlBundy and try not to be sarcastic.

Comment: Anyway, are we done here because it seems you have an explanation even if you find it hard to believe.